# MySQL order by clause with expression

Tags: sql-injection, mysql, sql-order-by

I am going through some starter material on SQL injections and while fuzzing, one SQL query I concocted was:`SELECT * FROM users ORDER by 3 and 0;` Now, shouldn't the part `3 AND 0` evaluate to `0`. But that doesn't happen. The query returns all users, ordered by the first column. The DB I am using is MySQL.

Comment: This is a pure SQL question. When you run into this problem, run it on a SQL install you own and test there by direct query.

Comment: @schroeder Thank you for your advice. But I have run this query on MySQL server, which is why I said the query returns all users from the table, which is something I wasn't expecting. I just wanted to know why, since as per what I understand `3 and 0` should evaluate to a `0`.

Comment: `ORDER BY` arranges the order of the selected result set but doesn’t change anything on what is being selected.

Comment: You need to look at how SQL uses `AND`.